# MySQL join with one table. List values with a where clause, then list values beneath

Tags: php, mysql, join

I am writing a small script for a bit of fun and to learn a little more about PHP/MySQL and I have come to a dead end with generating the menu. My intention is to generate a CSS styled dropdown menu where you hover over the menu items and then a list of sub pages is displayed beneath.

The pages in my script are stored in a MySQL table named 'pages'. Here is an example of the MySQL.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id   title         linkText    menu       pageContent
1    Home          Home        top        This is my home page.
2    Projects      Projects    top        This page is a list of my projects
3    Music         Music       Projects   This page is about my music
4    Photography   Photos      Projects   This page has photography work
5    Art & Craft   Artwork     Projects   This page is all about art and craft work
6    Contact Me    Contact     top        Send me a message
```

What I would like to be able to do with the MySQL statement is to list the items where the 'menu' field equals 'top' which would be simple.

```
SELECT title, linkText, menu FROM pages WHERE menu = 'top'
```

But the part I am stuck on is listing the top items then below each top item list the sub items to give an output like so.

```
Home
Projects
--Music
--Photos
--Artwork
Contact
```

I imagine this would be done with a mysql join, but after trying many different combinations and following a bundle of examples I can't seem to get it working.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Add some code, it is difficult to understand your question without code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want an answer in PHP I can give you :

```
try
{
  $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cours', 'root', 'root');
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
  die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
}

$answer = $bdd->query('SELECT linkText FROM stack WHERE menu = \'top\'');

while ($data = $answer->fetch())
{
  echo $data['linkText'] . "<br/> \n";
  $answer2 = $bdd->prepare('SELECT linkText FROM stack WHERE menu = ?');
  $answer2->execute(array($data['linkText']));
  while ($data2 = $answer2->fetch())
  {
    echo "--" . $data2['linkText'] . "<br/> \n";
  }
  $answer2->closeCursor();
}
$answer->closeCursor();
```

Which gave me the result HTML :

```
Home<br/> 
Projects<br/> 
--Music<br/> 
--Photos<br/> 
--Artwork<br/> 
Contact<br/>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that works exactly as required. It looks like all my tests with code were miles away from what I should have been looking at!

Comment: The code solves only issue where you have one parent menu and one submenu - parent >> submenu, in case that you would want to have more levels of submenu, lets say - parent >> submenu >> submenu, then it wouldn't work. If you use the code which I posted then you can have any depth of submenus.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
<?php
// SQL for creating database
/*
 CREATE TABLE `menu` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `linkText` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `menu` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `pageContent` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
*/

class Menu {
    /**
     * @var PDO
     */
    private $_dbh;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param PDO $dbh database connection
     */
    public function __construct(PDO $dbh){
        $this->_dbh = $dbh;
    }

    /**
     * Get menu
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getMenu(){
        return $this->getTree($this->getTop());
    }

    /**
     * Get top menu
     *
     * @return array
     */
    private function getTop(){
        return $this->_dbh->query("SELECT * FROM menu WHERE menu = 'top'")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    /**
     * Get children menu for specified parent menu
     *
     * @param array $menu
     * @return array
     */
    private function getChildren(array $menu){
        $stmt = $this->_dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM menu WHERE menu = :menu");
        $stmt->bindParam(':menu', $menu['linkText']);
        $stmt->execute();

        return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    /**
     * Get menu tree
     *
     * @param array $parents parent menus
     * @param array $tree tree representing menu
     * @return array
     */
    private function getTree(array $parents, array $tree = array()){
        foreach ($parents as $parent){
            $tree[$parent['id']] = $parent;
            $children = $this->getChildren($parent);

            if (!empty($children)){
                $parent['children'] = $children;
                $tree[$parent['id']] = $parent;
                $this->getTree($children, $tree);
            }
        }

        return $tree;
    }
}

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=stackoverflow', 'root', 'root');
$menu = new Menu($dbh);

echo '<pre>'; print_r($menu->getMenu());
```

Result is a tree (implemented by array) representing whole menu structure:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [title] => Home
            [linkText] => Home
            [menu] => top
            [pageContent] => This is my home page.
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [title] => Projects
            [linkText] => Projects
            [menu] => top
            [pageContent] => This page is a list of my projects
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                            [title] => Music
                            [linkText] => Music
                            [menu] => Projects
                            [pageContent] => This page is about my music
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 4
                            [title] => Photography
                            [linkText] => Photos
                            [menu] => Projects
                            [pageContent] => This page has photography work
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 5
                            [title] => Art & Craft
                            [linkText] => Artwork
                            [menu] => Projects
                            [pageContent] => This page is all about art and craft work
                        )

                )

        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [title] => Contact Me
            [linkText] => Contact
            [menu] => top
            [pageContent] => Send me a message
        )

)
```

You can find the code here as well: http://pastebin.com/NcmrJmY3